# For a positive semi-definite $d\times d$ matrix $A$, $ (\text{det}(AS))^{\frac{1}{d}}\leq\frac{1}{d}\text{Tr}(AS) $ for every $S\in\text{SPD}_{d}$.

Tags: determinant, trace, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

> For a positive semi-definite $d\times d$ matrix $A$,  $$
>  (\text{det}(AS))^{\frac{1}{d}}\leq\frac{1}{d}\text{Tr}(AS) $$ for
>    every $S\in\text{SPD}_{d}$.

I would like to show the above statement. If it is already asked, please share the link below. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: @James $\left(\Pi_{i}\lambda_{i}^{AS}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}\leq\frac{1}{d}\left(\Sigma_{i}\lambda_{i}^{AS}\right)$
Done?

Comment: Why do we need the positive semi-definite condition?

Comment: @kayak If not then the AM-GM inequality cannot be applied.

Comment: If you let $A = I$ and $S = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} 10 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 \end{array} \right ]$. If $d=1$, then $det(AS)^{\frac{1}{d}} = 50$ but $\frac{1}{d}Tr(AS) = 15$, and so the claim is false.

Answer (score 0):

> $$\left(\Pi_{i}\lambda_{i}^{AS}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}\leq\frac{1}{d}\left(\Sigma_{i}\lambda_{i}^{AS}\right)$$

The above inequality is done with the assumptions.